# Grep part of large file without spliting it

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

How can I `grep` a certain part of a large file from lines 1000 to 2000, up to line 1000 or from line 1000 for example?
I don't want to split the file in smaller files.

Comment: what is your grep pattern? are there perl specific regex e.g. look-behind/ahead? if just simple regex pattern, I suggest you using sed/awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use `sed` to pre-process. EDIT: adding a `q` per Kent's suggestion

```
sed -n '1000,2000{p;2000q}' file.txt | grep 'abc'
```

for line 1000 through end of file

```
sed -n '1000,$p' file.txt | grep 'abc'
```

Comment: if the file is huge, add a `q` at proper place is not a bad idea.

Comment: Or just `awk 'NR==2000{exit(0)}NR>=1000 && /pattern/' file.txt`

Comment: @tripleee, great idea. please add that in as an answer that I can +1

Comment: we don't know how does OP's grep line look like. That's why I posted the comment under the question. for the `grep 'abc'` the awk one-liner is ok, also your sed line could do the job without piping to grep. but if the grep line looked like `grep -P -A3 -B2 '(?<!pre)abc(?![^-./]after)'` the awk one-liner would be something different.

Answer (score 2):

As a minor improvement over the `sed` solution by @ravoori, refactor the `grep` into the `sed`:

```
sed '1000,$/pattern/!d;2000q' file.txt
```

If you have the pattern in a variable, use double quotes;

```
sed '1000,$/'"$pattern"'/!d;2000q' file.txt
```

Or equivalently in Awk:

```
awk 'NR==2000{exit(0)}NR>=1000 && /pattern/' file.txt
```

or with a variable

```
awk -v pat="$pattern" 'NR==2000{exit(0)}NR>=1000 && $0~pat' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

`head -2000 FILE.TXT | tail -1000 | grep XXX`

as the neatest solution because `head` does not have to read the huge file, just the first few N thousand lines. It essentially achieves what `q` does in the `sed` solution.

Comment: And the benefit of using three processes instead of one would be ...?

Comment: Can you measure the difference between 1 process vs 3 processes on one file? The benefit, as I see it is that it makes it clear that I am throwing away anything after 2000 lines and anything before 1000. Corresponds more closely to the specification as the OP expressed it. But then I do like the `sed` solution with `q`.